# Is there a module for saving current block setup?

Tags: blocks

Would be handy to be able to save the current block setup, so after one changes around blocks, it could be reset to a previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try either of these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Features Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra):

  > ... provides faux exportables (via Features) of several site-building components.
  >
  > To export a block, install FE Block, edit your block, give it a "machine name," export it with Features. You can export block settings (region settings, visibility settings, ...) of any block, and the content of blocks created with the Block module from Drupal core.
  >   The D7 version supports the Block Class, i18n block and Block Cache Alter modules.
- [Boxes](https://www.drupal.org/project/boxes):

  > ... a reimplementation of the custom blocks (boxes) that the core block module provides. It is a proof of concept for what a re-worked block module could do.
  >
  > The module assumes that custom blocks are configuration, and not content. This means that it is a reasonable action to ask for all blocks at one time, this is in fact exactly what the core block module does.